# Why isn't on change called to run an async function to update the thumbnail of List row view?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to update the thumbnail image of list view row. But swiftui refuses to update my image when it is updated.

The getArtwork method correctly gets the image but refuses to update the view.

The text updates fine except the image. MusicFile is a simple struct with a property called artwork that is of type Data.

```
struct PlaylistSongRow: View {

    var musicFile: MusicFile
            
    @State private var thumbnail: UIImage?

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Group {
                if let thumbnail = thumbnail {
                    Image(uiImage: thumbnail)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        
                } else {
                    Image(systemName: "music.note")
                        .resizable()
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .scaledToFit()
                       
                }
            }
            //not sure why this is not called.
            .onChange(of: musicFile.artwork, perform: { newValue in
                Task {
                    if let artwork = newValue {
                        thumbnail = await getArtwork(for: artwork)
                    }
                }
            })
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(musicFile.name)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                Text(musicFile.artist)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    .lineLimit(1)
            }
        }
        .task {
            if let artwork = musicFile.artwork {
                thumbnail = await getArtwork(for: artwork)
            }
        }
    }

    func getArtwork(for data: Data) async -> UIImage? {
        let image = UIImage(data: data)
        guard let image = image else { return nil }
        let size = CGSize(width: 500, height: (500 * image.size.height) / image.size.width)
        
        guard let thumbnail = await image.byPreparingThumbnail(ofSize: size) else { return nil }
        
        return thumbnail
    }
}
```

Comment: Music file isn’t capable of change it just has initial values

Answer (score 0):

Use `task(id:)` instead e.g.

```
.task(id: musicFile.artwork) {
```